# Facebook OAuth with Firebase web

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, oauth-2.0

With Firebase, when I use Facebook sign-in method, the first click on My Facebook button opens the pop-up window but don't log-in, only the second click on this button opens the pop-up window also and log-in into my success page.
Any idea why the first click did not get in ?
By the way it is the same behaviour with Google sign-in method as well.

Comment: Change your browser and check . Also drop more clues by checking developers console and checking if any error result there .

Comment: More elaboration on the error would help us understand .

Comment: I just put the code. tkx

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I juste added  $location.path('/success');  at the end of the function FacebookSignIn. And it works